# Get stack trace to string in MS VS C++

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio

I need to dump a lot of stack traces (for some debug issue, does'nt matter) in some places in my program. So i want to write some function like DumpCurrentStackTrace("dump.txt"); that dumps current stack trace to file "dump.txt". I need to do this in Microsoft Visual Studio, in C++ project. How can i implement this function (maybe some winapi functions)?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far or can you show us some code?

Comment: I want to write function that create dump of current call stack in windows, so i don't understand what code you want to see =)
I don't even know from what i must start. Can't find anything about that in google.

Comment: Have a look at the [c++ file I/O](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io) classes and functions

Comment: What?
How this can help me with problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See http://stackwalker.codeplex.com/ for a good example of how to read the stack trace for a thread, including writing it to a file.

Comment: thanks, it good example =)

Comment: Would the downvoter care to leave a reason?

Comment: It's intresting for me too.

Comment: Moved to https://github.com/JochenKalmbach/StackWalker